# not able to use scponly for the scp operation

Tags: linux, scp

I have installed `scponly` on my system under `/usr/bin/scponly`. However, when trying to perform `scp` operation from the external linux box, I got the following error:

```
onx-jozhao-01|~/dcu/scpTest$ scp test-config.bk joe@47.135.59.78:/tmp 
Password: 
/usr/bin/scponly: No such file or directory
lost connection onx-jozhao-01|~/dcu/scpTest$
```

The password authentication has passed.

Comment: Firstly how did you install scponly and second if you login to the system normally and run the command /usr/bin/scponly what happens?

Comment: What do you have in `sshd_config`? Isn't the user chrooted? Do you have the binary in `chroot`?

Comment: Concur with @timfletcher -- run the commands `file /usr/bin/scponly` and `ldd /usr/bin/scponly` and add the output to your question. "No such file or directory" indicates that there's something very wrong with your `scponly` installation.

Comment: Is `/usr/bin/scponly` definitely on the the server and not the client?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. Waveserver> ls -al /usr/bin/scponly 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19888 Sep 20 18:44 /usr/bin/scponly
Waveserver> ldd /usr/bin/scponly 
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb6eb0000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb6d84000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0xb6edd000)
Waveserver>

Comment: Nothing happening when running scponly: Waveserver> /usr/bin/scponly
Waveserver>

Comment: I built scponly and used  <file value='%attr(0555, root, root) /usr/bin/scponly'></file> to put it on my system. Is there any special requirement for the installation? Many thanks.

Comment: sshd_config
Port 22
Port 830
MaxAuthTries 3
UsePrivilegeSeparation no
Protocol 2
HostKey /flash0/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
LogLevel quiet
LoginGraceTime 2m
StrictModes no
UsePAM yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitRootLogin yes
AuthorizedKeysFile /flash0/ssh/users/%u.pub
KeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 10
ClientAliveCountMax 3
AllowTcpForwarding yes
MaxSessions 10
UseDNS no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
UseDNS no
Banner /etc/issue.ssh
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/sftp-server
Subsystem netconf /usr/sbin/netconf-subsystem-pro
AllowUsers